# xaml code works fine but code behind class's code doesn't work :(

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind

This is my xaml code

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
   <TransformGroup>
         <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" /> 
         <TranslateTransform Y="300" />
   </TransformGroup>
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

I did the same thing in code behind class
but the code doesn't give the expected result.
Can someone please help me to convert this to C# code?

Regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
tg.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform { ScaleY = -1 });
tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform { Y = 300 });

theCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
```